# Automatically redirecting to an anchor upon site entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a jquery plugin called Ascensor link: http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/#Home

It's used for doing one page sites with easy scrolling, vertical and horizontal, it uses a coordinates system [x,y] for every div.

By default, the browser loads up the site and goes to the first coordinate [0,0], but i'd like it to go to a particular anchor when the site is loaded up, one that isnt on the origin.

Basically, I need a script that has the user automatically go to the specified anchor upon site entry. 
It's probably not much, but I did some research and wasn't able to be sure.

I've been trying with 
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;http://www.othersite.com/mypage.htm" />`

But that's no good, as it goes in a loop.

Thanks for reading, hope I provided enough info.

Bab.

EDIT: I solved my issue using another technique, using another method than the one that would correspond to my inquiry. I'm sure this post can still be useful to the rest of the community, so feel free to answer the question.

Comment: Looks like you've given up quite easily. What else did you try except for the meta tag?

Comment: As I'm quite a noob with this stuff, and am learning, I wasn't quite sure what to look for... I haven't tried anything else, i'm having trouble with many aspects of this plugin, but they are getting solved as I watch and learn.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#anchorID").offset().top },{ duration: 1000});
});
```

Replace `anchorID` with your anchor ID, and set the duration to whatever you want for a smooth scroll.

Comment: This is acting strangely, once input in the html in script tags, I get scrolling action but not to the right anchor, the scrolling takes me to a "floor" but not the one I'm asking for. 
It seems the script is only doing scrolling, and not looking for the anchor tag.

Comment: Can you post some of your code - particularly the anchor?

Comment: Sure, here is the anchored div.

<div class="floor home" id="homebox"><span class="text">Home</span><div class="boite" id="homebase"><h1>Welcome to my website</h1>filler text</div></div>

Comment: Just checking on the obvious...you have replaced the `#anchorID` in the above code with one of your div IDs, not the class?

Comment: Yes of course, Here is how I input your code:`<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('html, body, div').animate({ scrollTop: $("#homebox").offset().top },{ duration: 1000});
});

     </script>`